# Pass data on each ChildViewController to next ChildViewController on UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have an object from Realm and i assign each control to object, what i want is to pass each object that i assign on each childVC to the next childVC.

I have the object initialized on my UIPageViewcontroller:

```
var artist = Artist()
```

I use this function to scroll to nextViewController :

```
func scrollToViewController(index newIndex: Int) {
        if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
            let currentIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: firstViewController) {
            let direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = newIndex >= currentIndex ? .forward : .reverse
            let nextViewController = orderedViewControllers[newIndex]
            scrollToViewController(viewController: nextViewController, direction: direction)
        }
    }
```

And i assign each textbox, label to this object on childVC FirstViewController:

```
artist.artistName = textField.text!
```

Same is on the next childVC SecondViewvController:

```
artist.genre = genres[0]
```

I want to pass each control value that i assign from previous VieController to the next ViewController, for example:

On my SecondViewController i want to have the previous value saved on artist.artistName and assign the value that i get from label. For example just to print the previous value on viewDidload.

```
class SecondViewController {
var artistNameFromFirstVC: String?
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ArtisName: \(artistNameFromFirstVC)")
        // Setup Views
        setupCollectionView()
    }
...
}
```

I have more than 2 childControllers, so i want to pass each previous values to next controllers.

I appreciate any help. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: this is not very clean but you can do something like...
     if let controller = nextViewController as? SecondViewController { // assign value } else if let controller = nextViewController ...

Comment: on every childVC ?

Comment: Also, if its the same object, you can pass it to all childVC.
You just have to create a protocol like: 
      protocol MyVCProtocol {
            var artist: Artist? 
      }
      class childController: MyVCProtocol {}
            (nextViewController as? MyVCProtocol).artist = artist
Helps?

Comment: I not sure what you mean, if you could post a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Helps?

```
struct Artist {
    var name: String
    var genre: String
}
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var name:String?
}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var genre:String?
}
enum ScrollController: Int {
    case first = 0
    case second

    init(with index: Int) {
       self = ScrollController(rawValue: index) ?? .first
    }
    var controller: (Artist) -> UIViewController {
        return { artist in
            switch self {
            case .first:
                let controller = FirstViewController()
                controller.name = artist.name
                return controller
            case .second:
                let controller = SecondViewController()
                controller.genre = artist.genre
                return controller
            }
        }
    }
}
func scrollToViewController(index newIndex: Int) {
    if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let currentIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: firstViewController) {
        let direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection = newIndex >= currentIndex ? .forward : .reverse
        let nextViewController = ScrollController(with: newIndex).controller
        scrollToViewController(viewController: nextViewController, direction: direction)
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do i get the `name` from firstViewcontroller to my SecondViewController ?

Comment: if you just are referencing to the same object...the value should change, right?